# Can we use akka.event.Logging to write logs in file?

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I have tried using log4j and slf4j with akka in scala and I am able to get log files. Can I achieve the same thing without using any external api other than akka APIs? By using akka.event.Logging I am able to print logs in console, but I want to print it in a file.

I have already tried setting log4j.properties file for my project in classpath and its not working when I am using akka.event.Logging.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you configured akka accordingl? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html

Comment: Yes I have configured according to this  doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to this http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html
you have 3 options:

1. Use `akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger` (to stdout, not for production)
2. Use `akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger` (logger by akka for SLF4J)
3. Use the SLF4J API directly (with **async** appender)

Your case is 2 or 3 (you use `log4j.properties`).
Therefore you should properly configure file `log4j.properties` for output in file.
And

- in case 2 (your desired case), you should use `akka.event.Logging`, for example: Logging.getLogger(system.eventStream(), "my.string")
- in case 3, you should use SLF4J API, for example: `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(...)`

Your case is 2, if you use in your akka config something like this:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

Comment: Will this configuration do? I did what you mentioned, with the below configuration, but I am still not able to get the log file.

log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d][%p][%c{1}][%t] - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.file=D:\\scalalogfile.log

Comment: I am able to see logs in my console by this, but no log file is created.

Comment: It is working now, but I configured in logback.xml....log4j.properties is not working.